# C Writing to absolute address does not update value

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, pagination, kernel

Im trying to write a basic page manager for my C kernel. The code goes like this:

```
#define NUM_PAGES 1024
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
#define NULL 0

#define IMPORTANT_SEGMENT 0xC0900000

struct page {
    void * addr;
    int in_use;
};

struct page CORE_FILE[NUM_PAGES];

void mem_init() {   
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        CORE_FILE[i].addr = (void*)IMPORTANT_SEGMENT+PAGE_SIZE*i;
        CORE_FILE[i].in_use = 0;        
    }
}

void * allocate() {

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        if (!CORE_FILE[i].in_use) {
            CORE_FILE[i].in_use = 1;        
            return CORE_FILE[i].addr;
        }   
    }

    return NULL;
}

int deallocate(void* p) {

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        if (CORE_FILE[i].addr == p && CORE_FILE[i].in_use) {
            CORE_FILE[i].in_use = 0;
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}
```

CORE_FILE is an array of structs containing just one field for telling if the page is in use and an address (im using contiguous addresses growing from IMPORTANT_SEGMENT = 0xC0900000).

When i call `allocate()` it returns me the correct `void*` which i cast for example to char, but when i write to the address it simply does nothing.

I have checked the address to which is pointing with GDB and is the correct one. 
But when i examine its contents they haven't been updated (Still 0).

```
void kmain(void) {
    mem_init();
    int * addr = (int*)allocate();
    *addr = 5;
}
```

Im giving qemu 4 GB of RAM executing with:

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 4G -kernel kernel -gdb tcp::5022
```

Perhaps im writing to non-existent memory or maybe im overwriting the address contents after. I don't know.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

[edit] This is the bootloader im using:

```
bits 32
section .text
        ;multiboot spec
        align 4
        dd 0x1BADB002              ;magic
        dd 0x00                    ;flags
        dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00)   ;checksum. m+f+c should be zero

global start
global keyboard_handler
global read_port
global write_port
global load_idt

extern kmain        ;this is defined in the c file
extern keyboard_handler_main

read_port:
    mov edx, [esp + 4]
            ;al is the lower 8 bits of eax
    in al, dx   ;dx is the lower 16 bits of edx
    ret

write_port:
    mov   edx, [esp + 4]    
    mov   al, [esp + 4 + 4]  
    out   dx, al  
    ret

load_idt:
    mov edx, [esp + 4]
    lidt [edx]
    sti                 ;turn on interrupts
    ret

keyboard_handler:                 
    call    keyboard_handler_main
    iretd

start:
    cli                 ;block interrupts
    mov esp, stack_space
    call kmain
    hlt                 ;halt the CPU

section .bss
resb 8192; 8KB for stack
stack_space:
```

My link.ld

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
 {
   . = 0x100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = 0x200000;
   .data : { *(.data) }
   . = 0x300000;
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
 }
```

Edit2: I compile with this

```
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin -m32 -c memory.c -o memory.o
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o memory.o kc.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with protected and real mode, when the computer boots it does so in 16 bit real mode, which makes you able to address 1 MB of data. Everything over that wont be suitable for reading/writing. If i changed the IMPORTANT_SEGMENT to 0x300000 it works.

Now i have to create and load my gdt, enable the a20 line, enable protected mode, set the registers and jump to my code.